# Derive asymptote algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’m working my way through an Australian year 10 level mathematics text book and have been asked to give the asymptotes for y = 1/x.

The book has only mentioned asymptotes once before in passing and whist I can both “see” the asymptote by looking at the graph and have read that

> If denominator′s degree > numerator′s degree, the horizontal asymptote is the x−axis: y=0.

I feel uneasy about merely memorising a rule, rote, without grasping a little of the proof behind it.  Or am I over-reaching in my attempts to understand the material being presented at this stage?

Many of the explanations on the web I’ve come across seem to be dealing with the idea at the level of calculus and I’m wondering, is there an algebraic approach to deriving the asymptotes to this kind of rule?

Comment: I don’t know if there’s a formal proof that doesn’t involve calculus, but the intuition of the proofs in calculus is basically this: as x goes towards infinity, it eventually gets massively big (I’m talking astronomically bigger than even billions, trillions, etc — numbers we can’t even fathom) and gets bigger and bigger forever. As that happens, $1/x$ gets smaller and smaller. As the denominator gets bigger and the numerator remains fixed, the fraction gets smaller and smaller. You can imagine how tiny it is when $x$ is massively big.

Comment: Thanks, that sumed it up nicely for me.

Comment: Thinking more about the massively big concept for other rational functions, say $y=\frac{x^2}{x^4-2}$, as x gets massively big, $x^4$ is going to be astronomically larger than $x^2$ to the point where $x^2$ becomes insignificant. Therefore as $x$ tends to infinity $y$ tends to 0. Hopefully both the intuition and looking at graphs will help convince you for now before you get into calculus. :)

Comment: Thanks once more :)

Answer (score 2):

The "usual" argument is going to involve explicit limit arguments.  However, when I teach this to my precalculus classes, I try to avoid these explicit limit arguments, and handwave a little.

When $|x|$ is very large, the behaviour of a rational function will be "dominated" by the leading terms.  The "right" way to demonstrate this is with limits, but we can build an intuition by noticing that if $m < n$, then
it will eventually be the case that
$$ |C x^m| < |x^n|. $$
In particular, if $|x| > \max\{ 1,|C| \}$, then
$$ |C x^m| = |C| |x|^m < |x| |x|^m = |x|^{m+1} \le |x|^n.$$
What this shows is that every term in a polynomial is eventually smaller than the highest degree (leading) term, which means that the overall shape of a polynomial is determined by the leading term.  A similar argument applies to rational functions.  When teaching this, I will often write something like
$$ \frac{a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_1x + a_0}{b_m x^m + b_{m-1} x^{m-1} + \dotsb + b_1 x + b_0} = \frac{a_n x^n + \text{junk}}{b_m x^m + \text{junk}} \approx \frac{a_n}{b_m} \frac{x^n}{x^m} = C x^{n-m}. $$
The function $x \mapsto x^k$ is a "primitive function" in my instruction, which can have one of only a few possible graphs:

[image]

These "primitive functions" are then scaled (and possibly reflected across the $x$-axis by) $C$.  Hence the asymptotic behaviour of a rational function is determined by the leading terms of the numerator and denominator.  You get a horizontal asymptote at zero if the denominator has larger degree than the numerator; you get a horizontal asymptote at $y = a_n / b_m$ if the numerator and denominator have the same degree, and $a_n$ & $b_m$ are the leading coefficients of the numerator and denominator, respectively; and you get unbounded growth otherwise.

**Note:** The graphs above are only useful for understanding the behaviour of a rational function when you zoom way out.  The function might look very different if you zoom in on it.

Answer (score 0):

If $p(x)=a_nx^n+\dotsb+a_1x+a_0$ then for $x>1$ we have $|p(x)|\le Mx^n$ where $M=n\times \max a_i$.  This implies that $|\frac{p(x)}{x^{n+1}}|\le \frac{M}{x}$. By a similar idea you can prove if $\deg q=m>n$, there is a constant $M$ such that $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\le \frac{M}{x}$.

This is what the algebra can tell you. For the rest you have to understand what asymptotes means. Asymptotes are supposed to estimate the value of function by a line for very big $x$. The above inequality show that $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is very small for big $x$. In fact, by choosing big enough $x$ you could make it smaller than anything you want. So the line $y=0$ would be a good estimate.

Of course if you understand projective geometry you can compute the asymptotes algebraically, but it need more machinery and I think it is better to first understand the analytic meaning.

Comment: Cheers.  I’m sure when I look back on your answer next year I’ll have a better understanding of what you are saying, but for now I get the general idea.